# Snap fabric.Line to 45 degree angle

Tags: fabricjs

I'm trying to play with `fabric.Line()` in fabricJS so that when the user starts drawing a line it snaps to one of eight angles at a 45 degree angle from the start point. It would be similar to holding down shift when using an Adobe product. Is that possible with fabricJS?

Comment: maybe fabric js `angle` property will helpful for this

Comment: @sharmask I tried playing with the angle property but no luck

Comment: Actually what kind of output you want ?.. i don't get it clearly. When user starts drawing a line or when user rotate line?

Comment: @sharmask when a user starts drawing a line, I want the line to be confined to a 45 degree angle.

Comment: can you give me some visual example ... user only draw a line Straightly right .. then how?

Comment: ok.. in Photoshop we hold shift key and move mouse up  line automatically snap 45 ... something like this right...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### EDIT march 2020

- The snap rotation is now a built in feature in fabric.js

#### original answer:

You have to check the angle you are building during mouse move
and approximate it to a 45° degree line.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
  selection: false
});

var line, isDown, points;

canvas.on('mouse:down', function(o) {
  isDown = true;
  var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
  points = [pointer.x, pointer.y, pointer.x, pointer.y];
  line = new fabric.Line(points, {
    strokeWidth: 2,
    fill: 'red',
    stroke: 'red',
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'center'

  });
  canvas.add(line);
});

canvas.on('mouse:move', function(o) {
  if (!isDown) return;
  var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);

  var startX = points[0];
  var startY = points[1];
  var x2 = pointer.x - startX;
  var y2 = pointer.y - startY;
  var r = Math.sqrt(x2*x2 + y2*y2);
  var angle = (Math.atan2(y2, x2) / Math.PI * 180);

  angle = (angle) % 360 + 180;

  if (angle <= 22.5 || angle >= 337.5) {
    angle = 0;
  } else if (angle <= 67.5) {
    angle = 45;
  } else if (angle <= 112.5) {
    angle = 90;  
  } else if (angle <= 157.5) {
    angle = 135  
  } else if (angle <= 202.5) {
    angle = 180
  } else if (angle <= 247.5) {
    angle = 225
  } else if (angle <= 292.5) {
    angle = 270
  } else if (angle < 337.5) {
    angle = 315
  }
  angle -= 180;

  var cosx = r * Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180);
  var sinx = r * Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180);
  
  line.set({
    x2: cosx + startX,
    y2: sinx + startY
  });
  canvas.renderAll();
});

canvas.on('mouse:up', function(o) {
  isDown = false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="c" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: `angle = parseInt(((angle+22.4)%360)/45 )*45` shortens the if-then-elseif  loop.

Comment: Just to add now the rotation snapping is a  built in fabricjs feature

Answer (score 1):

Ok here we know line starting X1 and Y1 and line end X2 and Y2 points.we know also know 45degree of angle.

So here we apply some math to get output.

in X1 and Y1 point stay there and X2 and Y2 points want to travel with 45degree angle.

`X2 = Math.cos(angle * Math.PI/180) * distence + startX
Y2 = Math.sin(angle * Math.PI/180) * distence + startY`
[tanks for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17456783/javascript-figure-out-point-y-by-angle-and-distance)

here

```
startX = x1
startY = y1 
angle=45
distence = current.mouse.x-x1
```

So we can get x2,y2 with 45 degree angle

lets try this on `fabricjs`

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
  selection: false
});

var line, isDown, points;

canvas.on('mouse:down', function(o) {
  isDown = true;
  var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
  points = [pointer.x, pointer.y, pointer.x, pointer.y];
  line = new fabric.Line(points, {
    strokeWidth: 2,
    fill: 'red',
    stroke: 'red',
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'center'

  });
  canvas.add(line);
});

canvas.on('mouse:move', function(o) {
  if (!isDown) return;
  var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);

  var startX = points[0];
  var startY = points[1];
  var distence = pointer.x - points[0];
  var angle = -45

  x2 = Math.round(Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * distence + startX);
  y2 = Math.round(Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * distence + startY);
  console.log("x2 >>> " + x2 + " y2 >>>>> " + y2)

  line.set({
    x2: x2,
    y2: y2
  });
  canvas.renderAll();
});

canvas.on('mouse:up', function(o) {
  isDown = false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="c" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
```